# Excel - Remove number for duplicated text in table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that contains activity scores and training dates for my team. I'd like to remove the number which appears after duplicated text. For example, there are 10 columns in a table titled 'Activity Date', how do I remove or prevent Excel from adding 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. after each 'Activity Date'?

Comment: You can't have duplicate header labels in a structured table.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data along with expected results, will help us to fix it !!

Comment: In table it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Comments, you simply don't. Careful consideration would suggest why Excel would require this.

However... if you can make do with not having the numbers APPEAR to be there (as in, you simply wish the labels to be "Activity" a bunch of times to the eye and do not actually care that they are actually unique.

Lots of people ask questions assuming the basis proposed is the only possible one. So, if you don't care that the numbers are really there, you just don't want them displayed, then bearing in mind that all the headers in a Table are text, and nothing else, period, just format the text.

So, a column displays "Acitivity2" in white text on the standard darkish blue header fill color? Then select the cell, press `F2`, highlight the offending "2" at the end of the word, and format ITS text color to be that background color. You can achieve that by  right-clicking on it and using the font color control, and a couple other ways. So the "2" is still there, Excel is happy, but no one can see it. In fact, even if you center the headers and they look a wee bit wrong, the filtering dropdown controls help make the text actually look centered, not off to the left a wee bit.

Excel lets your apply formatting character-by-character to TEXT, but to no other kind of data entry. SADLY. But that works just fine for you here.